# Automatically clear input from an element within ShadowDOM using Angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, lifecycle, shadow-dom

I am using Ionic to create an autocomplete input but am having an issue with the browser autofilling the input with invalid data. I need to be able to clear it using Angular.

PS: I have added `automcomplete="off"` but it is not respected.

Below is the HTML for Ionic's `ion-input` which I am trying to target:

```
<ion-input #inputElem
           [autocomplete]="enableBrowserAutoComplete ? 'on' : 'off'"
           [name]="name"
           (keyup)="getItems($event)"
           (tap)="handleTap($event)"
           [(ngModel)]="keyword"
           (ngModelChange)="updateModel($event)"
           (ionFocus)="onFocus($event)"
           (ionBlur)="onBlur($event)"></ion-input>
```

Within my component I have the `updateModel()` function which checks the input on changes and clears it if it is invalid. However, angular's change detection does not notice if the browser autofills.

Or, say if you manipulate it in the console:

`$('input.searchbar-input.sc-ion-searchbar-md').value = 'J'`

So I am trying to find a way to clear the keyword if there is not a valid selection. My most successful attempts is using life cycle hooks such as `OnChanges`, `DoCheck`, and `AfterViewCheck`, but clearing the keyword is not enough. I have to clear the input inside the shadow dom because the value did not propagate yet. So within the function I have to get the element using a promise (I suspect this is the real problem). Which "works" as long as I keep a break point within the lifecycle function. The second I remove the breakpoint the browser tab completely freezes.

```
@ViewChild(
  'inputElem',
  {
    read:   ElementRef,
    static: false
  }
)
private inputElem:ElementRef;

[..]

ngOnChanges():void {
    if (!this.hasFocus) {
      if (this.clearInvalidInput && this.selected === null) {
        if (this.keyword !== '') {
          this.keyword = '';
        }

        if (this.inputElem && this.inputElem.nativeElement) {
          this.inputElem.nativeElement.getInputElement().then(
              (element) => {
                if (element.value !== '') {
                  element.value = '';
                }
              }
          );
        }
     }
   }
}
```

I have posted a work around as an answer but am leaving this open as it feels very hacky.

Comment: could you do a satckBlitz of that?

Comment: I created a stack blitz but the `ion-input` won't show. https://ionic-lpebqc.stackblitz.io @JSmith

Comment: Hey! could you send an edit link please?

Comment: you needed to add wrap around `ion-item`to make it work

Comment: tell me when you are available maybe we can chat and I'll try resolve the problem. If I can of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround, but it is not a preferred solution.

```
ngDoCheck() {
  if (this.inputElem && this.inputElem.nativeElement) {
    if (this.inputElem.nativeElement.children && this.inputElem.nativeElement.children.length !== 0) {
      if (this.inputElem.nativeElement.children[0].children && this.inputElem.nativeElement.children[0].children.length !== 0) {
        if (this.inputElem.nativeElement.children[0].children[0].value) {
          this.inputElem.nativeElement.children[0].children[0].value = '';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```